# Windows 2008: throttling network bandwidth of a process

Tags: windows, bandwidth, windows-server-2008, rate-limiting

Is it possible to limit the network bandwidth of a process on Windows 2008? We need to run a long running upload but don't want to saturate the network (we have time).

Comment: Possible duplicate on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in to Windows (that I am aware of, anyway) that will throttle individual processes. You will have to use a third-party tool like [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/).